# Show $X \sim Y \iff X,Y \in L^2(\Omega, \mathscr{A},P) \text{ and } X=Y \text{ P-a.s is an equivalence relation}$

Tags: probability-theory

**Problem**

Show that the relation $X \sim Y \iff X,Y \in L^2(\Omega, \mathscr{A},P) \text{ and } X=Y\text{ P-a.s is an equivalence relation}$

**Attempt:**

$"\Leftarrow":$

To show that $X \sim Y$ given that $X,Y \in L^2(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P) \text{ and } X=Y \text{ P-a.s}$ i have to show reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity.

But i'm having a hard time understand how?

Do i use that $E\{X^2\}<\infty,E\{Y^2\}<\infty \text{ and } E\{XY\}<\infty$ or do i use something with the inner product? I'm having some trouble getting started on this problem.

If you have any hints, it'll be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What definition of $L^2(\Omega, \mathscr{A},P)$ were you taught? Don't you rather mean $\mathscr L^2(\Omega, \mathscr{A},P)?$ (i.e. the space of square-integrable functions of which $L^2$ will later be defined as the quotient space by $\sim$)

Comment: "To show that $X \sim Y$ given that $X,Y \in L^2(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P) \text{ and } X=Y \text{ P-a.s}$ i have to..." I think you misunderstood the problem. You are not at all asked to show that. This is (a not completely correct rewording of) the *definition* of $\sim$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflexive:

For all square integrable $X$, we have $X=X$ surely and thus almost surely.

Symmetric:

For all square integrable $X,Y$, we have:

$X=Y$ a.s. if and only if $Y=X$ a.s.

Finally, the big thing, transitive:

For all square integrable $X,Y,Z$, suppose $X=Y$ a.s. and $Y=Z$ a.s. We must show that $X=Z$ a.s.

Well...

$$P(X=Z) = P(X=Y \cap Y=Z)$$

$$= - P(X=Y \cup Y=Z) + P(X=Y) + P(Y=Z)$$

$$= - P(X=Y \cup Y=Z) + 1 + 1$$

$$= - P(X=Y \cup Y=Z) + 2$$

$$= 1$$

if and only if

$P(X=Y \cup Y=Z) = 1$

Well...

$\{X=Y\} \subseteq \{X=Y \cup Y=Z\}$ so monotonicity of probability tells us $P(X=Y \cup Y=Z) = 1$

---

Note: I've never done this in my life, and I have no idea the relevance of the square integrable thing. I don't see even see what's the problem if they're not integrable.

Comment: @Flems i'm not sure if i'm correct because indeed i have no idea if the square integrable thing is correct. i've never done this in probability classes. then again, we were in an applied maths course so we didn't even know what equivalence relation meant.

Comment: Your proof of transitivity is not correct because e.g. your first equality, $P(X=Z) = P(X=Y \cap Y=Z),$ is (in fact true but) unproved. Better replace it by $\ge.$ Anyway, the question is a duplicate (see the link above.)